# Need to get the charaters available before comma

Tags: excel, vba

Consider if a string has multiple comma's (,) i would like to get the 3 characters that are present before each comma in excel VBA macro. for example in the string "AR6, AB4, UUF, ABG, UUG, AC4, ABF," in this string i would like to get the value of AR6 first then print then second AB4 and so on. the string may contain n number of Commas. Could you please help me to get this.

Comment: `Split(yourstring,",")` which will return an array that you then can loop through.  Google will have many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
 Dim st As String
 Dim a As Variant
 st = "AR6, AB4, UUF, ABGtt, UUGyy, AC4, ABF,"
 a = Split(st, ",")
 For i = 0 To UBound(a)
  Debug.Print Left(Trim(a(i)), 3)
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: oh, you made it community. Didn't know you could do that^^;

Comment: @findwindow,yes and  now I know that I can do that